# Synchronization of processes in the shell?

Tags: multithreading, shell, unix, synchronization

I am forking off a bunch of processes, and I want to create a "Barrier" for my main original process to wait until all of the other processes finish. The code flow looks like so:

```
#...the main thread is executing now, and reaches this foreach loop:

foreach arg (myArgs)

    some_command arg & #these are the processes being forked off

end

#I want the main thread to WAIT here until all the above processes finish!

#... More code below here for the main thread to continue with
```

I'm not sure what synchronization primitive I want, or even what's available in the unix shell environment. Maybe something like a barrier for the main thread?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bare `wait` will wait for all child processes to exit.

> #### wait: wait [n]
>
> Wait for the specified process and report its termination status. **If
>           N is not given, all currently active child processes are waited for,
>           and the return code is zero.**  N may be a process ID or a job
>           specification; if a job spec is given, all processes in the job's
>           pipeline are waited for.

Comment: Alright cool, much simpler than I thought. So if I do "wait" without an argument then I should be good because all of those forked processes will count as child processes?